# Get items by category paginated using Cloud Firestore order by date asc or desc

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm changing an Android app to look like Netflix. (A list  of carrousels displaying items).
My DB is Cloud Firestore in the firebase platform.

This is the structure I'm using to show the items by category ordered by Date desc or asc

```
{
  name: "Item",
  categories: {
    catId1: true,
    catId2: true,
    catId3: true
  }
}
```

the problem I'm having is I don't see any of the items there because I need to create indexes for every catId (which makes no sense to me) and on top of that I need to split the results in order to paginate the request. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correct, but I think you might be looking for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, but I'm trying to build something similar to what Netflix does with their main screen. The categories will have items and they should be order chronologically or by name. The problem is I have to create indexes to make the query with order work. And my indexes are the ids of the categories, which means for every category created I would need an index and I haven't found a way to create them that is not manual for every category created.

Comment: Hey guys I changed the question, maybe this way it would be easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: These indexes should automatically be created. From the documentation page I linked before: "This technique relies on the fact that Cloud Firestore creates built-in indexes for all document fields, even fields in a nested map."

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm not sure if I getting your point. But right now I'm receiving this error:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: url?create_index=EgZldmVudHMaIwofY2F0ZWdvcmllcy5WaUJnOFZWNlVGSzAyd2NJQXR4WhACGg0KCXN0YXJ0RGF0ZRACGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAI

Comment: The categories are created by the users and I don't see a way to create those indexes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

With your current data model, what you're asking can't be done efficiently with a single query.  You will have to perform multiple queries and join/merge the results in your client code.  This is very typical for NoSQL databases, and the only way around it is to duplicate (denormalize) your data in such a way that prevents the need for extra queries.

Comment: Hi Doug, that is not my model right now. Actually, I'm using the categories inside the items. However, this does not seem to be a good approach because I need to create an index for each category created in order to get them to bring data. And those indexes aren't dynamically created for each category. What should I do then?